# Using HarshiCorp Vault for Windows RDP

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-login

Is there any way I can use Vault to create a OTP for login for Windows remote desktop?

Or are there any better alternatives to create an OTP as an admin and send it over to the user for login?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the question but I believe the closest thing to your requirement is: https://github.com/scarolan/painless-password-rotation

Use a Powershell script to rotate the password every x hours and store it in vault. Authorised users in Vault can request the credentials.

This way you'll have an audit log within Vault of who acquired the credentials and a limited TTL for the credentials based upon your rotation above.

Not ideal but the closest if you really need users to RDP onto hosts.